# How to log in with DotNetOpenAuth with known credentials?

Tags: c#, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I'm new to DotNetOpenAuth and I just need to log in with known user credentials (my server needs to log in to another app to perform some admin stuff). Now, I can't seem to find a way to avoid all the redirection and callback stuff, I just need to give user credentials to DotNetOpenAuth and log in with that. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That very much depends on which protocol you're trying to use.  OAuth 1.0(a) requires redirects.  OAuth 2.0 allows for password credential grants (what you're trying to do), which requires that you're using DotNetOpenAuth 4.x and either the `WebServerClient` or `UserAgentClient` classes.  On either class you achieve your goal by calling the `ExchangeUserCredentialForToken` method.

Comment: Unfortunately I am Using OAuth 1.0, so I had to find another work around, but thanks for the answer anyway. At least it confirms that I can't do it the straightforward way.

Comment: Please, could you indicate what is the namespace of the DesktopClient class, I tried to do this using the DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.UserAgentClient but I had no sucess.

Comment: @DanielPeñalba Sorry for the typo. I meant `UserAgentClient`. If it didn't work for you, please feel free to post a new question on SO, or to dotnetopenid@googlegroups.com